# Javascript datatypes visual

Tags: javascript, object, types

I'm making a visual reference of javascript for myself and everyone who likes to have it when it's done, to get a better understanding of core JavaScript.

Now I'm not sure if I got the datatypes part right, I'm basing the visual on the book "JavaScript the definitive guide"

So I would be glad to hear if my structure is right.

[image: the visual]

Revised version of the visual:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure is right. JavaScript has five primitive data types: String, Number, Boolean, Undefined, and Null. Object, array and functions are the compositive datatypes. This link might be helpful for you to clear your thoughts.[Data types in Javascript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7wkd9z69%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Objects contain properties and methods; arrays contain a sequential list of elements; and functions contain a collection of statements.A function is a data type in JavaScript, not so common in many other programming languages. This means that they can be treated as something containing values that can be changed. This makes them composite data types. ALso, javascript do not really have class as "CLASS" in java or python. Everything is prototyped from another object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Mostly the composite part was where I got stuck, as you are saying array should be next to object instead of being part of it. But where should "function" be, below object or next to it?

Comment: Everything in js is objects, even numbers but my point being is: it might be easier to visualize array that way. In real sense, Javascript arrays are a type of object used for storing multiple values in a single variable.

Comment: If placed a revised version in my question, did you mean this or should function be between object and array?

Comment: Function can be between object and array. Like I said, for Js, function can be treated as something containing values that can be changed.